# VPN hanging on gnome-keyring (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: vpn, gnome-keyring

I've been having problems with gnome-keyring.  Previously, the Chromium browser was hanging and Seahorse didn't show a Login keyring.  However, 
a `apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-keyring` seemed to fix that.

Now, when I try, through the xfce panel, to connect to my VPN which has a saved group password, it hangs for a long time (several minutes).  Eventually, I get a password prompt without the group password filled in.

Here are the contents from syslog:

> Mar  9 14:28:43 laptop NetworkManager[1038]:   [1520627323.6783]
>   audit: op="connection-activate"
>   uuid="554a8005-cf6e-45ae-b4c4-197a9062e96d" name="HCS VPN" pid=1933
>   uid=1000 result="success"
>
> Mar  9 14:28:43 laptop NetworkManager[1038]:
>     [1520627323.6800]
>   vpn-connection[0x1e5c820,554a8005-cf6e-45ae-b4c4-197a9062e96d,"HCS
>   VPN",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
>
> Mar  9 14:28:54
>   laptop org.freedesktop.secrets[1946]:
>   SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
>
> Mar  9 14:30:54 laptop
>   org.freedesktop.secrets[1946]:
>   SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
>
> Mar  9 14:32:09 laptop
>   NetworkManager[1038]:  [1520627529.2410]
>   vpn-connection[0x1e5c820,554a8005-cf6e-45ae-b4c4-197a9062e96d,"HCS
>   VPN",0]: Failed to request VPN secrets #3: No agents were available
>   for this request.

Comment: Killing and restarting gnome-keyring is a work around.  But I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: The `ubuntu-keyring` package is just the public keys for apt, to verify package signatures. Don't see how that would have helped. I've had Chromium hang in the past, due to `dbus-user-session` being installed though.

Comment: dbus-user-session is not installed.  Neither is flatpak.  Maybe the reinstallation didn't help, but there is definitely something messed up about gnome-keyring.